# how to receive value from Runnable Thread in java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, class, methods

I have a problem when I want to receive result using other class.

Let's say I have two methods in my class "NewImage" : fct_1() and fct_2()

fct_2() is launched in a new Thread and fct_1() doesnt.

so in my new other class where I want to show the result:

this one works fine :

```
Bitmap received=null;
final NewImage NewImage_1 = new NewImage ();
received = NewImage_1.fct_1();
```

and this doesnt

```
Bitmap received=null;
final NewImage NewImage_1 = new NewImage ();
received = NewImage_1.fct_2();
```

My Methods are :

```
public static Bitmap fct_1()
{
code 1
}

public static Bitmap fct_2()
{
new Thread(new Runnable() {public void run(){
code 2
}});
}
```

Is there a way to fix this please?

Comment: Can you describe your problem with calling the second method in more detail? What exactly "doesn't work"? Does the method throw an error/exception? Does it never complete and crashes your whole JVM with an Out Of Memory message?

Comment: Please provide more details, Whats the problem??

Comment: The only difference is that : I'm using fct_2 in a new Thread .